# File not updating on localhost

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-2010, localhost

I am pulling my hair here. I think I am falling into som really basic stuff but here is my error. I have built a simple webpage with the following "tree-view".

[image]

in my readjson.js I read from my json-file stored in json/label.json. However!

Even if I have updated my json-file it reads the FIRST version of the json-file when I started. Using Google Chrome and have tried to refresh the browser, clean my build an so on. Still wont update the json-file on localhost.

**Have anyone else run into this and how do I solve it?**

Comment: @SamLeach Yep. Does not solve it.

Comment: Can you confirm that the correct version of the file is getting deployed to your webserver / target directory?  If so, it would appear to be a caching issue.  If not, it is a deployment issue.  If it's the latter, you may try changing the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer" in your solution explorer window... ?

Comment: How often does this cache naturally clean itself?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried to bring up the developer console (ctr shift j) and right click on the refresh icon using the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" option?

Comment: the refresh button referred to here is the web page refresh button to the left of the URL

Answer (score 8):

1. **Ctrl + Shift + Del**
2. **Clear all cached data***

*In the newer versions of browsers it can be different like clear **only files and images cache*** or something else similar to this.

3. **Ctrl + F5** should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac you right click the reload button and click "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". Sometimes, though, it's enough to just do a "Hard Reload" (`cmd + shift + R`).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is seeing this and none of these solutions work, try running the application with

```
npm run dev
```

instead of

```
npm start
```

Fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on console and clear console history and right click on refresh button on your browser and hard reload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Chrome is reading the data from cache files. You should:

1. Clear cookies and cache files.
2. Reload the page.

It worked for me.