# Localhost and 127.0.0.1 show different content in web browser

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, localhost, lamp

When I enter **127.0.0.1** to web browser, it shows page **/var/www/index.php** as I expected, but when I enter **localhost** it shows "*a simple hello world*" html page which I cannot find in the computer.

I used find, grep and other similar tools, but no luck.

Can you please tell me why localhost shows another content then 127.0.0.1 in the web browser?

I have installed **apache, mysql and php** on my ubuntu 14.04 and **Document Root** is set to **/var/www/**. There were previously installed apache, postgresql and php (which I removed), maybe should I check some old exist config files?

**/etc/hosts** is set to

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

Comment: Very interesting issue. Have you an `apache.conf` file, of any virtualhost ? Perhaps there is a config. See files in **/etc/apache2/** directory

Comment: No, I do not use any virtualhost.

Comment: You should test before asking a question, here your problem was obvious with a minimum of test.

Comment: I have tested but other things because I did not expect such a trivial issue...I think this question will save time for somebody else. You may perhaps consider not using SHOULD in polite communication.

Comment: Browser use cache, so refresh page without cache is useful. Sorry for 'should', I'm not English.

Comment: @AnthonyB I've had the same issue as OP, and indeed, it looks like the browser stored it in the cache. Refreshing the page via F5 did not change it. Opening in a different browser "resolved" the issue. Consider turning your comment into an answer - it helped me.

Comment: actually, maybe also check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723801/file-not-updating-on-localhost -- try Ctrl+F5, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to press **F5** button in order to refresh the localhost page in my web browser.

Now the content is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As requested in comment I post it as answer.

Web browsers use cache and in some cases your changes are not reloaded.
So refreshing using **Ctrl+R**, **Ctrl+f5** or **disabling cache** in your settings may be useful.