# how to find file being shown for localhost

Tags: localhost

When I go to my localhost, it displays simply the text "It works!".

I think I tried to make a webapp a while ago and this must be a leftover from that. I simply don't understand enough to know how to update this.

I know that localhost represents my computer, and the address used can be defined in my /etc/hosts file. This file displays the following:

- 127.0.0.1 localhost
- 255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
- ::1             localhost

I've used grep/find to look for all files on my computer that have "It works!" or that are html, and can't seem to find this.

Another question that seemed related but didn't help:

- [Localhost and 127.0.0.1 show different content in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212704/localhost-and-127-0-0-1-show-different-content-in-web-browser) (I refreshed the cache and nothing happened)

I am using a Mac.

Please help with this very dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out.

I first realized I could get it to stop by running: sudo apachectl stop.

But when I run sudo apachectl start, it comes up again. So it must have something to do with Apache.

Then I looked in /etc/apache2 and found the conf file, httpd.conf.

This said that the DocumentRoot is DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents", and in this directory was the html file.