# Changes to JavaScript File Not Showing on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to experiment with a website by changing some of its javascript code. The steps that I am following are:

- Open up Chrome Dev Tools and then navigate to the sources tab. 
  Add a folder to the workplace.
- Right click on the javascript file that I want to alter and select Map to File System Resource.
- Select the matching javascript file in the new folder that I added.

However, when I make changes to the javascript file in the new folder and reload the webpage, the changes do not appear. The changes are also not present when I open up dev tools and look at the javascript file. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Dev Tools - Workspace mapping mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351513/chrome-dev-tools-workspace-mapping-mismatch)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723801/file-not-updating-on-localhost

Answer (score 3):

refresh the cache when you reload with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> if you're on Mac. On windows i think it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>